# android facebook posting image from SD card

Tags: android, facebook, image, post

i need to post a image from SD card to my fb wall
for that i have done this

```
private void postToFacebook(String review) {    
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
        mProgress.show();

        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

//      params.putString("message", review);
        params.putString("message", GlobalVariable.getMsg());
        params.putString("name", "Dexter");
        params.putString("caption", "londatiga.net");
        params.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
        params.putString("description", "Dexter, seven years old dachshund who loves to catch cats, eat carrot and krupuk");
    //  params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44"); this runns fine and post img
        //params.putString("picture","file:///mnt/sdcard/IMAGE.PNG");this do nothing niether post string nor img
        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());
```

edited

```
 Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test.jpg");
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
           data = baos.toByteArray();


        //     Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
          params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

Logcat

```
02-24 14:12:11.501: I/System.out(16979): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
02-24 14:12:11.501: I/System.out(16979): buffer returned 
02-24 14:12:11.511: I/System.out(16979): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
02-24 14:12:11.511: I/System.out(16979): buffer returned 
02-24 14:12:11.792: D/Facebook-Util(16979): POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
02-24 14:12:11.792: W/Bundle(16979): Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:11.802: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(16979): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:11.812: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:11.832: W/Bundle(16979): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:11.842: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:11.872: D/SensorManager(16979): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@428008b8
02-24 14:12:11.872: D/Sensors(16979): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-24 14:12:11.872: I/Sensors(16979): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-24 14:12:11.882: D/SensorManager(16979): JNI - sendDelay
02-24 14:12:11.882: I/SensorManager(16979): Set normal delay = true
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): Key method expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:14.805: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1370)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
02-24 14:12:14.815: W/Bundle(16979):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
02-24 14:12:22.743: D/SensorManager(16979): registerListener :: handle = 4  name= MPL accel delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@428008b8
02-24 14:12:40.312: D/SensorManager(16979): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@428008b8
02-24 14:12:40.312: D/Sensors(16979): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-24 14:12:40.312: I/Sensors(16979): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-24 14:12:40.312: D/SensorManager(16979): JNI - sendDelay
02-24 14:12:40.312: I/SensorManager(16979): Set normal delay = true
02-24 14:12:40.402: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16979): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-24 14:12:40.402: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16979): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

what wrong i am doing?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void postPhoto() {


    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mProgress.setMessage("Posting To Facebook...");
    mProgress.show();
    // Posting image to Facebook
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);


    try {

        Bitmap bi = decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard("filepath", 600,
        480)
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
        params.putString("name", "Test");
        params.putString("caption", "Test");
        params.putString("description", "Test");
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        mAsyncFbRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                new WallPostListener(), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public Bitmap decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(String filePath, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: file path= file:///mnt/sdcard/IMAGE.PNG?

Comment: what is data? in this?

Comment: data is byte array representation of the image file.